# Video Editing Rig Struggles Need a Solution

Tags: premiere, hardware, windows, adobe-media-encoder

I have picked up more video clients and thus I need to be able to edit faster. I have been trying to update my machine on a budget to get the most performance for my dollar.

**Machine**

- Windows 10 Pro OS with Adobe CC 2018
- Core i7 5820K 6 Core Stock Clocked
- 16 GB Corsair DDR4 3000 Ram Running at 2133

  - I have 16GB of the same model more on my desk ready to go in
- nVidia GTX970 4GB SC
- NVME Boot Drive 512GB
- Samsung 850 PRO 256GB
- WD Blue 500GB Export Drive
- 1.8 TB RAID 0 Array Assets Drive via Startech PCIE Raid Card

  - EVO 850 1TB
  - SANDisk 960GB SSD Plus
- Corsair CX500M Modular 500W PSU

**Issues**

1) Renders are still taking what I consider to be longer than they should.
A 1 minute clip with Color Correction (Basic Lumitri Color Correction is taking about 9 minutes. If I try to add RedGiant Denoiser II, it'll take an hour, minimum.

2) Scrubbing simple timelines is not fluid at all. Sometimes I'll go to play a clip and it'll stutter. Stopping playback and starting it again will fix it but it shouldn't be that hard.

It's exaggerated by adding the cc layer. What I typically do is add the cc and other effects to an adjustment layer, turn it off while editing and then on when done, but I'd like to use a 4k monitor in the future and do the playback review on that.

3) CPU Will peak at 100% but ram never gets above 13gb or so and disk useage or saturation of the link never gets above 1%. I feel like this isnt really an issue but I want to make sure it's not. I know I can upgrade my cpu and it may still get to 100%.

4) Can not export with CUDA acceleration

**Thoughts**

As mentioned, I know I can upgrade the CPU but with the current cpu bugs, I'd rather wait for the next release. Feels like the smart thing to do maybe.

I don't think the raid array is helping me or the sandisk isnt quick enough. There is definitely a stutter when I run blackmagics disk speed test.

I could switch to NVMEs for all of the drives, but I don't think that disk speed is my problem but then again, I'm coming to you for help.

I will spend whatever makes sense here. I am hoping to grow this business so an investment would make sense but at the same time, I don't want to go mac pro yet.

I've updated everything driver wise and bios wise. Still no love. I'm kind of getting frustrated with it.

**What I'm Looking For**

What changes should I make to this rig?

What can I do to fix the issues I've mentioned?

Am I wasting time with RAID at this point? Should I just buckle down and buy larger SSDs?

I know the EVO 850 is fast but there are definitely faster drives, just way more expensive.